# Visual feedback for value update

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have `contenteditable` `td` elements in a table. I'm using bootstrap and `table-hover` (so the colour changes when you hover over a row. On blur of the `td` I do an ajax request that updates the value on the server and then I get a response that indicates success or the error. On success I want to indicate that the value has updated successfully. Right now I'm doing this:

```
var trueColor;
trueColor = $(element).css('backgroundColor');
$(element).animate({
  backgroundColor: '#cce2ff'
}, {
  duration: 100,
  complete: function() {
    $(element).delay(10).animate({
      backgroundColor: trueColor
    }, {
      duration: 900
    });
  }
});
```

So I'm using the complete callback of the first animate to put the colour back to what I want it to be. The code works but the problem is obviously if you're hovering over the element when it sets `trueColor`. I've thought of using css animations but the main thing was that I didn't know how to get a "flash" kind of effect (I think maybe `keyframes` would help but I don't know how to use them let alone how browser compatible they are).

So the question is basically how do I achieve the effect? I don't mind whether it's css or javascript and I welcome superior suggestions if you think there's a better way to give this sort of visual feedback to a user.

**Update**
Thanks to @chiliNUT I am removing the class to get the colour but the problem was then that jquery's animate had styled the element and so hovering was broken on modified cells. So now I also `removeAttr("style")` to get rid of that once we're done

```
  var trueColor;
  $(el).closest('table').removeClass('table-hover');
  trueColor = $(el).css('backgroundColor');
  $(el).closest('table').addClass('table-hover');
  $(el).animate({
    backgroundColor: '#cce2ff'
  }, {
    duration: 100,
    complete: function() {
      $(el).delay(10).animate({
        backgroundColor: trueColor
      }, {
        duration: 900,
        complete: function() {
          return $(el).removeAttr("style");
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: i dont know bootstrap so how does the `table-hover` part work exactly?

Comment: @chiliNUT.. check it [out](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-hover-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the hover effect while its doing the display update, then restore it once the display update finishes. You can get the table element containing the td with `$(element).closest('table')` and then remove the hover effect with `removeClass('table-hover')` and then put it back with `addClass('table-hover')`, so

```
var trueColor;
//remove hover
$(element).closest('table').removeClass('table-hover');
//get original color
trueColor = $(element).css('backgroundColor');
//restore hover
$(element).closest('table').addClass('table-hover');
//..rest of your original code
```

Comment: That's pretty smart - I wouldn't wait to restore the `table-hover` class though. `.animate()` is going to override any css so I would restore it right after getting trueColor.

Comment: Yeah the same thought had occured to me, really I guess you could just do it immediately, like remove class, get trueColor, addClass, and that would be enough

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of removing the class - I just thought about trying to remove the hover state (which apparently can't be done). Thanks man!

Comment: @jcuenod NP. I've edited to just do it all at the beginning without waiting til the end to restore the hover. Consider upvoting or accepting if this solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for the prompt, I was kind of hoping someone would swoop in with some kind of spectacular solution with some totally unexpected tool (like css animations) but this works well. Thanks.